# How to connect to Docker MySQL databse from a different virtual machine

Tags: mysql, docker

I have two `EC2` instances.

1. vm1 - has mysql server running as a `Docker` container
2. vm2 - has mysql client installed.

Now I want to connect from `vm2` to the mysql container running in `vm1`. In `vm1`, the container is exposed `3306` to the container port `3306`

I tried first telnetting the port as:

`telnet <ip-of-vm1> 3306`

and I get the below error:

> Trying 10.128.15.6...
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

I even allowed the firewall rules to `allow all` inboud. And `mysql` container running without any errors.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: does it work when you try to connect from the same instance?

like this:

telnet localhost 3306

Comment: are these two instances in the same network?
the IP addresses you are using are they private IP addresses or public ones?
if they are private, do instances share the same subnet?

Comment: @FedorShabashev yes it works. and yes they are in the same subnet and I can ping each other

Comment: can you show the list of the inbound rules for the instance where the mysql database hosted?

Comment: @FedorShabashev one correction, i tried to access the mysql from the same vm (vm1) using `mysql -h localhost -P 3306--protocol=tcp -u jana -p` and it gives me the error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jana'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Well, incorrect password should not be related to the “connection refused” error. 
I think it would still be good to check inbound rules for the EC2 instance. 

I’m talking about this table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCdTs.png      
How does it look for your instance?

Comment: My concern is, i can log into the mysql using `docker exec -it <container-id> mysql -u root -p` but when i try to connect just by `mysql -u root -p` it doesn't work